# How could I make related entries load faster?

Tags: templating, database, elementcriteriamodel

I need to show a list of users (around 400). No problem, the list loads in 1.5s, for which I could use `{% cache %}` to speed it up.
Now, the problem arises whenever I want to display the title of an entry related to the user. The log shows 400 extra queries, so a query per user, if I do this:

```
{% for user in user %}
    {{ user.relationFieldName.first() }}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems a bit faster, but not fast:

```
{% for user in user %}
    {{ user.relationFieldName.find()[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to get this information directly when querying for users? Or is there another way to speed this up?

Would eager loading these relations through a plugin help? And if so, what service/model/record would I have to extend to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [template hook](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail) to eager load the related data from a plugin and cache the results for future requests.

Comment: I'm especially interested in the eager loading part. Could you give an example of how to do that? Can't seem to get it working. I have some criteria (group, limit f.i.) and want users with related entries. A little help to get me on the right path would be greatly appreciated!